# Sort files numerically by name, then by parent directory in BASH

Tags: bash, sorting

So, I'm facing a pretty edgy problem. I have a bunch of directories, named by numbers (0, 1, 2, and so on...), containing files also named by numbers.

When I use `find . -type f | sort -nr`, I got my list of files sorted, but by parent directory first, and then by file name.

Like this :

```
/0/0.png
/0/1.png
/0/2.png
/1/0.png
/1/1.png
/1/2.png
```

Instead of this (what I would like) :

```
/0/0.png
/1/0.png
/0/1.png
/1/1.png
/0/2.png
/1/2.png
```

How could I get the last behavior to happen ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Does the path always have two elements? Like `dir/file.png`?

Comment: Yes. No empty directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/` as the separator, first sort by the filename, then by the directory name:

```
find . -type f | sort -t/ -k3,3n -k2,2n
```

Comment: Awesome ! It worked. What does the -k<n> stands for ?

Comment: As documented in `man sort`, `-k FROM,TO` tells sort to use the columns in the interval FROM..TO to sort, the final `n` means numerical sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
find . -type f | sort -n -t "/" -k3
```